# Clarification on the concept of arrays in PHP

Tags: java, php, arrays

I am new to PHP programming, but have written Java before. In Java, the idea of arrays is that you have a collection of several objects of a particular class (including the data types such as int, String, etc).

In PHP I have seen the description of arrays as being along the lines of "a variable that has multiple values assigned to it".

My question is: can you describe the PHP array in the same way as you would do so for an array in Java? If not, what is the difference?

I'm thinking there is a difference due to the syntactic differences:

Java:

```
int anArray[] = new int[10];
```

PHP:

```
$anArray = array();   // I am aware of the difference in typing
```

Any advice or explanation much appreciated!

Comment: Refer to my comment - I am aware of the weak-typing in PHP. What I'm asking is whether you can describe a PHP array as a collection of objects as you would in Java.

Comment: *An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys.*. Go through the docs you will get all. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot describe a PHP array as being the same as an array in Java.

The reason is that a Java array's elements must all be of the same type, whereas an array in PHP can contain values of different types.

**For example in PHP:**

```
$arr = ["string", 1, 1.2]; // A string, int and double / float
```